# Fancybox thumbnail scroll

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using [Fancybox lightbox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

I don't have room in my `<div>` for stacked thumbnail images. Most lightboxes scroll horizontally, with a left arrow image left of the thumbs and a right arrow image right of the thumbs. To do this, I would have to start over with a whole new lightbox, as I cannot read the code well enought to implement the scroll function myself.

Can anyone give me a piece of code that I can throw in there to allow my thumbs to slide, rather than just set it to `overflow:auto;` which with only give me a scrollbar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's generally expected that you put forth some amount of effort to solve the issue yourself (and include the relevant code in your post). It's generally frowned upon to ask for code to be given to you. You can read more in the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Hope that helps!

Comment: `I cannot read the code well enough` Don't be lazy, check the gallery examples at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples